# Bound on Coefficients of Elliptic Curve

Tags: reference-request, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties

**Problem:** For a given point $Q:=(x_j,y_j)$ on 2-D,

*is there always an elliptic curve*   $E:=y^2=x^3+ax^2+b$ with a point $P:=(x_i,y_i)$ on it,

such that  $nP=Q$ and $(|x_i|)^k >ab$,

where $k\leq \frac{(n-\sqrt2)}{ 2}?$

Here,  $n$ is the scalar multiple of point $P:=(x_i,y_i)$. $P, Q \in E(\mathbb{Z})$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**Question:** Provided there is always an elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+ax^2+b$  with a point $P$ such that  $nP=Q$ ,

is it true that there exists point $P$ such that  $(|x_i|)^k >ab$ where $k\leq \frac{(n-\sqrt2)}{ 2}, n>0?$ How to prove or disprove it?

**Attempt:** So far I found no related results, this is probably due to lack of knowledge of terminology on elliptic curve, I know about Hall-Lang Conjecture, Baker's theorem (which is not helpful in this case).

**Post Script:** Please, let me know about result, terminology (for searching), method related to my question.

Comment: Are the coefficients $a,b$ fixed, or can we choose $a$ and $b$ to find an elliptic curve with this property?

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo  Hello professor, sorry for the late response, for a given point $Q$, we can find multiple pairs of $a,b$ (containing the given point $Q$), so we choose the best possible (probably the smallest possible) pair that satisfies our rest of the conditions, in that sense, they are not fixed.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo, did my comment clarify properly? Any comment on the problem?

Comment: See Example 3.3 in Silverman's "The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" in Chapter IX.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo, the example ends saying " the numerators and the denominators tend to have about the same number of digits."... I am having hard time to see how that helps, if possible please provide some hints in the direction that helps to solve the problem, thank you.